# MS Sharepoint 2007 - Site Deleted But Link is Still Displayed

Tags: sharepoint

We have a site on our Sharepoint which was deleted, however the links to the site still exist. Obviously, when you click the link it just goes to a 404 error but I don't know how to delete the site from our Sharepoint.

I know at one point I fixed this same exact problem by going to a tree of our sites and deleting it from the tree. However, at the moment I can't seem to find where I did that before.

Can somebody please lend a hand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Figured it out, but for others in this situation it was...Site Actions > Manage Content and Structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, but for others in this situation it was...Site Actions > Manage Content and Structure

Answer (score 1):

At a command prompt: IISRESET /NOFORCE

Restarting IIS will often force an immediate flush of the cache that keeps this site in the navigation.  Worked for me in the same situation as yours.